# Need to identify this cable

Tags: power, batteries, cables

I recently bought [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00YP823NA) product from Amazon, but need to get a splitter for the 20V output. I need to know what to look for though, and cannot identify what kind of cable this is / what to search for.

The print on the cable is

> (UL) SPT-1 2X20AWG VW-1 105°C 300V E307922 WL
>
> C(UL) SPT-1 2X0.519²(20AWG) FT2 105°C 300V WL +LF+

Please let me know what kind of cable / splitter to look for. Thank you!

Comment: you're going to need to measure the plug, measure the size of the hole and the diameter of the plug, (eg; use a drill bit to measure the hole)

Comment: I had a caliper in hand. It is 0.213" outer diameter (5.42mm), and 0.0855" inner diameter (2.26mm) @Jasen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats sounds like a 5.5mm x 2.1mm "barrel" connector, the most common size.

Do a search on `5.5 2.1 Y cable`

The actual print on the cable just describes the flexible part of the cable, not the connectors on the end.

Comment: This worked perfectly. Sorry I didn't accept earlier, I just forgot haha.